# Add the searching value from parameter in this function

Tags: java, arrays

This question follows my brevious one on how to [Return value of smallest index of repeated number in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632919/return-value-of-smallest-index-of-repeated-number-in-array).

In this function given to me by @Andreas:

```
private static void printFirstIndexOfRepeated(int[] values) {
    Integer firstIndex = null;
    Map<Integer, Integer> mapValueToIndex = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        Integer prevIndex = mapValueToIndex.put(values[i], i); // put() returns old value, or null
        if (prevIndex != null && (firstIndex == null || prevIndex < firstIndex))
            firstIndex = prevIndex;
    }
    if (firstIndex != null)
        System.out.println("First index of repeated: " + firstIndex);
    else
        System.out.println("No repeat found");
}
```

**Function test:**

```
int [] array = {10,5, 4, 3, 5, 6}; 
printFirstIndexOfRepeated(array);
```

**Output**

`First index of repeated: 1 // it looks for 5 and return the value of smallest index of repeated 5 in array.`

Due to my lack of programming knowledge with Map, I'm new and I know only Array. I need some help to transform this function and add another parameter like (int number) to decide witch number I'm looking for and not automatically

The desired one: `printFirstIndexOfRepeated(int[] values, int number)`

Comment: Yes, you get the point, when I enter `number=5` it return 1. When I enter `number=4` it return 2(because it appears only one time)

Comment: Ok, and do you want the function to return a number or to just print the result? And what if the number you entered is not in the array?

Comment: Hoops, managing if the number is not in the array is not implemented yet and the function to return the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So because you basically just want the index of the first occurrence of a given number inside an array, you don't need the `Map` at all. Instead you can just use a simple for loop:

```
private static int printFirstIndexOfRepeated(int[] values,int number) {
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if(values[i] == number){
            //System.out.println("The first index of " + number + " is " + i);
            return i;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(number + " is not a member of the array.");
    return -1;
}
```

This function returns the first index of a given number or `-1` if the number was not found. You can uncomment the `print` lines to also get an output if you like (or just delete them).